# When li selected add class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the class of div(#pension) when I click `<li>` inside div(#age).

Example: When li with class `under60` is clicked,  add class `under` to div(#pension) and when li with class `over60` is clicked, add class `over` to div(#pension).

```
    <div id="age" class="uf-filter">
    <div class="uf-title">age</div>
        <ul class="uf-tags">
            <li class="under60"><a href="#under60">under60</a></li>
            <li class="over60"><a href="#ove60r">ove60</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="pension" class="uf-filter">
    <div class="uf-title">pension</div>
        <ul class="uf-tags">
            <li class="yes"><a href="#yes">yes</a></li>
            <li class="no"><a href="#no">no</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#age li').click(function() {
                $( '#pension' ).removeClass( "active" );
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you clarify the expected result? what's the issue? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `class` of li - `over60` and `under60`

```html
<style>
  .under {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .over {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="age" class="uf-filter">
  <div class="uf-title">age</div>
  <ul class="uf-tags">
    <li class="under60"><a href="#under60">under60</a></li>
    <li class="over60"><a href="#ove60r">ove60</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="pension" class="uf-filter">
  <div class="uf-title">pension</div>
  <ul class="uf-tags">
    <li class="yes"><a href="#yes">yes</a></li>
    <li class="no"><a href="#no">no</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.under60').click(function() {
      $('#pension').removeClass("over");
      $('#pension').addClass("under");
    });

    $('.over60').click(function() {
      $('#pension').removeClass("under");
      $('#pension').addClass("over");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.under60').on('click', function(){
   $('#pension').addClass('under');
});

$('.over60').on('click', function(){
   $('#pension').addClass('over');
});
```

Hope this helps.